# Where are these verses from?

Tags: poetry

Can someone tell me from which poem these verses are?

> "Das Unverfängliche gibt uns kein Gleichnis,
>   das Unzulängliche, hier wird´s Ereignis."

I think it is from Goethe.

Comment: Search engines say that the following lines are in a [poem by Volker Braun](http://opablog.twoday.net/stories/1809808/comment): "Das Unverfängliche / Gibt uns kein Gleichnis; / Das Unzulängliche / Hier wird’s Erreichnis. / 
Das fein Geplante / Ist doch zum Schrein. / Das Ungeahnte / 
Tritt eisern ein." Google Books gives a link to a book by Kai Köhler, _Volker Brauns Hinze-Kunze-Texte_; a footnote on p. 147 say that this is an allusion to Goethe's _Faust_. However, I do not know where in Faust this alludes to. By the way, thank you for putting me on to Volker Braun: it's a terrific poem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the end of Goethe's Faust II:

> Alles Vergängliche
>   Ist nur ein Gleichnis;
>   Das Unzulängliche,
>   Hier wird's Ereignis;
>   Das Unbeschreibliche,
>   Hier ist's getan;
>   Das Ewig-Weibliche
>   Zieht uns hinan.

[Text](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Goethe,+Johann+Wolfgang/Dramen/Faust.+Eine+Trag%C3%B6die/Faust.+Der+Trag%C3%B6die+zweiter+Teil/5.+Akt/Bergschluchten)

So the poem of Volker Braun (see Eugene Seidel's comment) plays with the famous original.